# How to store a command output as a variable while erroring out if it fails?

Tags: bash, variable, command

I am trying to do an if statement based on a variable that is command, for instance:

```
ssh_location=$(which ssh)
```

My problem is that, I want to store this **only** if it exists on the system so I can do further processing with the binary, else I want to echo out an error string. This is what I am trying and having no luck with:

```
if ["$ssh_location"] ; then
    echo "it exists"
else 
    echo "does not exist"
fi
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
./test.sh: line 6: [/usr/local/bin/ssh]: No such file or directory
does not exist
```

(it definitely exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking if the file exist, you are trying to execute a command with the path `["$ssh_location"]`, which does not exist.

The syntax to check if the file exists is:

```
if [ -f "$ssh_location" ]
```

You are missing the spaces inside the brackets (yes, they are needed) and the `-f`. Without the `-f` you would evaluate the return code of the `ssh` command.